# Getting the max value of attributes from a list of objects python

Tags: python

I have data like id, start_time, duration, end_time

```
data = (
    <data 1 10 6.5 16.5 datacode>,
<data 2 12 7 19 datacode>,
<data 3 14 5 19 datacode>,
<data 4 9 7 16 datacode>,
)
```

Here i have to find end_time max list object and if end_time has more then one list objects

```
2  12 7 19 ->  
3  14 5 19 ->
```

i have to consider late start_time list object to modify like add 20-end_time(20-19) = 1 and add to duration 5 to 6

```
3 14 5 19 to update like 3 14 6 20
```

Please need help to find the solution

```
[d for d in data if d.end_time == max(d.end_time for d in data)]
```

Comment: What's the problem with your list comprehension?

Comment: I suggest you find the `max` one time like `maxval = max(d.end_time for d in data)` and then do `[d for d in data if d.end_time == maxval]` so that it's an O(n) process instead of O(n^2)

Answer (score -1):

You should evaluate the maximum value outside of the list comprehension so it's not re-evaluated on each iteration.

```
end_times = [d.end_time for d in data if d.end_time]
# max breaks when there's a None value in the iterable
max_value = max(end_times) if end_times else None
# This will still work if max_value is None, I'm not sure if that's what you need.
values = [d for d in data if d.end_time == max_value]
```